# Hibernate: Error in named query because of colon ":" in comment

Tags: java, hibernate, exception

I'm writing a native Sql namedQuery, it's insert statement looks like the following:

```
insert into myTable (
   column1,
   column2)
values(
   'value1'
   ,'value2' /* value2: is very important */
)
```

running the above block gives exception: "Error in named query", but when I remove the colon from the comment as following:

```
 insert into myTable (
    column1,
    column2)
 values(
    'value1'
    ,'value2' /* value2 is very important */
    )
```

everything runs fine, any explanation?

EDIT:
I can copy my real statement here but it's really long one. The above is just sample.
Here is the exception stacktrace:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries: insertSalesDocument
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:435)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1385)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:860)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:779)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    ... 194 more
```

Actually it took me couple of hours to know why I'm getting this exception since my insert statement looks correct and works properly when I copy it to Oracle Sql Developer. It looks to be a bug with hibernate namedQuery parser or something.

Comment: Please take some effort to format the question. Make it readable so people will like to help you ! more details : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate parses the SQL and tries to find any parameter in native queries. But the parser is limited and will not recognize the comment as something ignorable.

You can escape the `:` with `\`:

```
insert into myTable (
   column1,
   column2)
values(
   'value1'
   ,'value2' /* value2\: is very important */
)
```

Comment: Escaping special character using '\' works but such behavior still seems odd since hibernate can recognize the comment and ignore whatever I write there, yet, the colon ':' and question mark '?' still confuse it.